# hp-uft : what does this application error log say?

Tags: hp-uft

After an update, UFT is not running Testcases in UI ..ie simple F5 is not doing anything. On analysing the application log, this specific entry is found however has no record anywhere and no resolution. Can anyone shed some light ?

```
2019-12-10 16:38:02,264 LogCatASSERT [  33] ERROR MIC_LOG_ASSERT. Expression: (spQTExecutableTest) != 0 Func=CQTTestExecutionEngine::Run File=e:\ft\qtp\win32_release\xx.x.xxxx.x_clean\qtp\backend\executionengine\app\qtexecutionengine\qttestexecutionengineimpl.cpp Line=272 ThreadID=8064
```

thanks

Comment: am using 14.03 and following updates were installed KB4530715 and KB4489899

Comment: This looks like a bug in UFT, you should contact UFT's support.

Comment: yes, however today their site is under maintenance (at least the account creation page) and am not able to create an user account to post this to them. Thanks again.

Comment: I think there is an Patch for UFT 14.03.

Comment: @jonas yes indeed , however all of them are installed . Am not sure if microfocus released a new one for that version this year ( 2019 )

Comment: Try installing UFT 14.53 or even UFT 15.00

Comment: am limited to upgrading to 14.52 , however that isnt that stable from my experience hence downgraded to 14.03